# Why Python is too slow compared to FFI

Tags: python, ctypes, ffi

To illustrate the performance difference, I compare the execution time of some function in pure Python and a function that executes the same algorithm implemented in C. First, let's measure the execution time in pure Python:

```
def fibonacci(n: int):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    
    return fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1)

for _ in range(1000000):
    fibonacci(12)
```

Execution time:

```
$ /usr/bin/time nice python fibonacci.py
       29.66 real        29.52 user         0.06 sys
```

The Python implementation does the computation in a loop, with a total running time of 29.66 seconds. What about the FFI? Let's write some unsophisticated library code in C:

```
int fibonacci(int n);

int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    return fibonacci(n - 2) + fibonacci(n - 1);
}
```

And let's call this function from Python using the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module, as follows:

```
import ctypes

C = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./fibonacci.so')

C.fibonacci.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int,)
C.fibonacci.restype = ctypes.c_int

for _ in range(1000000):
    C.fibonacci(12)
```

Execution result:

```
$ /usr/bin/time nice python fibonacci-ffi.py
        1.09 real         1.01 user         0.01 sys
```

Pretty good, 1.09 vs. 29.66 --- 29 times faster. However, I do have a few questions:

- What can be improved in the Python implementation to bridge the gap?
- Why is the execution time difference so significant?

Comment: The difference is big, because Python is slow: weak typing, GIL, interpreted. Also you run a tight loop in raw Python, even with your ctypes variant: fibonacci call is probably dominated by the loop. Python is slow (GIL, interpreted, weak typing), this is especially visible in tight loops. One way to improve performance is to move entire loop to C. The less raw Python does, the faster it gets.

Answer (score 1):

> What can be improved in the Python implementation to bridge the gap?

You can use [Numba](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [Cython](https://cython.org) or [PyPy](https://www.pypy.org) to improve speed (numba or pypy can be faster, but you sometimes need to modify code)

> Why is the execution time difference so significant?

As mentioned by @freakish, python is interpreted, dynamically typed language with GIL which leads it to be pretty slow. CPython (most popular python implementation) also (unlike PyPy) don't have JIT compilation, but one of cpython goals in the nearest future is to impove python speed (From 3.10 new python versions become faster and faster)